# find combination of items when the dates overlap in R

Tags: r, associations

The following data contains four columns: `id` (individual id), `item` (factor), `purchase_dt` (purchase date), `supply` (days supply for each item).

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
item <- c("a","b","b","c","a","e","f","c","d")
purchase_dt <- c("2000-01-01","2000-01-15","2000-03-15","2000-04-01",
                 "2001-05-01","2001-05-15","2001-05-25","2001-06-20","2001-07-05")
supply <- c(20,10,30,20,30,30,30,20,20)

df <- data.frame(id,item,purchase_dt,supply)
df$purchase_dt <- as.Date(df$purchase_dt)
```

What I wanted to do is find the combination of items that were consumed together at individual level. For this, one needs to use both `purchase_dt` and `supply` and check whether overlap occurred.

Using this data set and for `id`=1, we can see that "a" and "b" were consumed together, and "b" and "c" were consumed together. Here are the reason.

The first item ("a") was purchased on `2000-01-01` and lasted for until `2000-01-20` (after adding the 20 days supply minus 1). I subtracted 1 since we include the first day.

The second item ("b") was purchased on `2000-01-15` and lasted until `2000-01-24`. So both items “a” and “b” can be combined.

The same logic applies to the rest of the data. Note that sometimes we have overlap for more than two products as we see for `id`=2.

Here is the output file I wish to generate:

[image]

Bonus: I am wondering if this can be done in dplyr, and the faster the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I don't quite understand your expected output. For `id = 2` there is overlap between `purchase_dt` and the previous `purchase_dt + supply - 1` of *all* entries. So according to your rules, shouldn't they all be combined?

---

Assuming you made a mistake for `id = 2`, you can do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(grp = cumsum(
        purchase_dt > lag(purchase_dt + supply - 1, default = first(purchase_dt)))) %>%
    group_by(id, grp) %>%
    summarise(comb = toString(unique(item))) %>%
    select(-grp) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id comb
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 a, b
#2     1 b, c
#3     2 a, e, f, c, d
```

Explanation: We group by `id`, create group labels based on date overlap between `purchase_dt` and the previous `purchase_dt + supply - 1`, then concatenate-summarise `item` entries by `id` and `grp`.

Comment: I likewise am confused about the overlapping rules.